# How to easily consume an API response, but add some additional flags to the response?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I am using an API that returns some data to me about photos, but I want to add a flag to the response I get called `favorite: boolean` so I can easily manage whether or not the photo is a favorite or not.

The vanilla response from the API looks something like this (but much simpler):

```
{
  "photos": [
    { "id": 1001, "url": "site.com/img/1001" },
    { "id": 1002, "url": "site.com/img/1002" }
  ]
}
```

I am wondering if there is a way to add the `favorite` flag so that the object I work with looks like this:

```
{
  "photos": [
    { "id": 1001, "url": "site.com/img/1001", "favorite": false },
    { "id": 1002, "url": "site.com/img/1002", "favorite": false }
  ]
}
```

Here is my code where I get the response from the API:

```
  getRecentPhotos(): Observable<any> {
    let photos =  this.http
      .get(this.getRecentPhotosUrl)
      .map((res: Response) => {
        return res.json();
      })
      .catch(this.handleError);
    return photos;
  }
```

Is it possible to add the `favorite` flag to the response I get back from that function?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have most of the code, you just need to add `favorite` flag in mapper,

```
.map((res: Response) => {
    let _result = res.json();
    _result = _result.map(_x => {
          _x = {favorite: false};
          return _x;
    })
    return _result ;
  })
```

Comment: nice!  thank you.  And what if there are cases when responses are really nested?  The API I am using also has stuff by location, where it looks like`[ { id: "the location", results: []}, {id: "the location", results[]}]`.  What about adding the same favorite tag for such a case?  Just curious if there is some issue there.

Comment: It will work you  just have to make sure you are taking right properties and applying null checks ...

Comment: Hi Madhu.  I am having some issues doing that :(  I tried to write another map within the function you mentioned above, but not sure if that is correct since I have a key whose value is an array, and I just need to do the same on it.

Comment: Can you update response JSON on which you want to apply map? and what is the result you are looking for?

Comment: oh sorry Madhu!  Thank you for the response, but I just figured it out!  I was doing one thing wrong.  Thank you so much :)  Basically I have to map on the property twice nested.